# JavaFX Unselect item on TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a TreeView, when I select an item, a tab opens with the corresponding information.
But when I close the tab and try to open it, it does not appear because the item has already been selected. And I need to first select another, and then click on it again.

I use this.

```
fileView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue == null)
        return;
    System.out.println("Selected File : " + newValue.getValue().getAbsolutePath());
    if (newValue.getValue().isFile()) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I see 2 solutions to the problem.

1) remove the selection label from the item

2) replace the listener

But I didn’t succeed.
I will be glad to your solutions.
Please provide a code snippet for example

P.s. please do not lower my reputation, I'm really interested in my question

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the selection after opening a tab:

```java
fileView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
        System.out.println("Selected File : " + newValue.getValue().getAbsolutePath());
        if (newValue.getValue().isFile()) {
            // Open a tab here...

            /* Clear selection */
            Platform.runLater(() -> fileView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: unclear questions get suboptimal answers, don't they ;)

Comment: @kleopatra shouldn't they?

Comment: well, without more details from OP it's mere guessing, IMO - not overly helpful to anybody. On the other hand, once the OP comes back, maybe she'll feel motivated to provide those .. who knows ..

Comment: @kleopatra brute-force

Comment: @kleopatra Some action is performed after a selection is changed in a `TreeView`, when the user goes back to the tree and tries to do the same thing with the same item, no change is fired. The same action can't be performed on the same tree item since no change happened. I believe this is what OP is asking.

Comment: if so, the selection change is the wrong trigger ;)

Comment: `EventHandler` on the tree cell is a better solution I think. What is your idea?

Comment: nothing without further details about what the OP _really_ wants - I don't like guessing games and I never (well, very rarely, only if extremely bored) answer x-y-questions, doing so is an utter waste of time, in my experience ;)

Comment: I _am_ killing time here

Comment: .. at the price of pointing future readers into the wrong direction (clearing the selection is 99.999999% wrong, only an extremely small probability that's the only option to solve whatever problem)? How about walking the dog, she'll be delighted <g>

Comment: @kleopatra not a fan.